# Query redis data after a certain Timestamp

Tags: java, redis, timestamp, jedis, redisjson

So I want to query all redisJsons that were inserted to the Redis cache after a certain timestamp .My redisJsons have a field like this one :

`GENERATION_TIMESTAMP : "2023-05-22 16:49:14.8052438"`

Is there a way to query them without using a sorted Set where we store the keys sorted by their timeStamps?

So a certain use case would be that I have a class that takes as argument a Timestamp , and returns all redisJsons that were saved to the cache after this timeStamp .

I expected something like using an index in the RediSearch module , I also tried to send all the redisJsons in a stream and query by using xrange , but this doesn't work for my use case .

Comment: What did you get using RediSearch?